# Unit Testing CRM 2011 Workflow Activities using the Moles Framework

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, moles

Anyone know where i can find some tutorials on how to unit test CRM 2011 Workflow Activities using the Moles framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing custom workflow activities via the Moles Framework
http://tech.brucechoi.com/?p=380